Find the orthogonal trajectories of families for system of curves $(\frac{dy}{dx})^2=\frac{a}{x}$
The first step in finding orthogonal trajectories is to eliminate a.
$$2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{a}{x^2}$$
$$\\ (\frac{dy}{dx})^2=\frac{a}{x}$$
$$\\ a = x(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$$
$ \text{When we insert this into: } 2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{a}{x^2} \text{ we get}:$
$$\\ 2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}{x^2}$$
$$\\ 2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{x}$$
$$\\ 2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{1}{x} \frac{dy}{dx}$$
The next step is to replace $\frac{dy}{dx}$ with $-\frac{dx}{dy}$. However, the left side has a second-degree derivative, how do we do such a replacement on the left side?

I'm not sure this makes sense: If $a$ is a free parameter, then the graphs of the curves $y(x)$ satisfying the differential equation for some $a$ is a $2$-parameter family of curves, and through a generic point $(x_0, y_0)$ (say, $a > 0$, so that $x > 0$), for any slope $m$ there is a solution $f$ of the o.d.e. satisfying $f'(x_0) = m$ for some $a$ (namely, $a = x_0 m^2$). On the other hand, if $a$ is a fixed value, so that only one curve in the family passes through each point, we shouldn't eliminate $a$.
